# Equal command in T-SQL written twice - works once, doesn't the second time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my T-SQL code:

```
;with tmpFolderPermissions(fp_folder, DataItem, fp_modify) as 
(
    select 
        fp_folder, LEFT(fp_modify, CHARINDEX(',',fp_modify+',')-1),
        STUFF(fp_modify, 1, CHARINDEX(',',fp_modify+','), '')
    from dbo.tblFolderPermissions

    union all

    select 
        fp_folder, CAST (LEFT(fp_modify, CHARINDEX(',', fp_modify+',') -1) AS VARCHAR(200)),
        STUFF(fp_modify, 1, CHARINDEX(',',fp_modify+','), '')
    from tmpFolderPermissions
    where fp_modify > ''
)
select fp_folder, DataItem
from tmpFolderPermissions
```

And it works fine, as a result I get a table with about 200 rows. However, if above that whole code I add the same command as above:

```
select fp_folder, DataItem
from tmpFolderPermissions
```

so basically, if I write this twice in a row, the first command shows me 200 results, which is good, but the second gives me this error:

> Invalid object name 'tmpFolderPermissions'.

Why does it give me an error, when it executed a milisecond ago?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmpFolderPermissions` is a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). And CTE's cannot be reused in multiple querys as it is part of the query itself. So the second time you call it, it doesn't exists.
Use a temp table or view instead.

Quote from link:

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and lasts only for the duration of the query.

Comment: Note: a single select in this context don't exclude a self join

Answer (score 0):

This is because tmpFolderPermissions is a CTE, CTE is sth like tmp table and it's not accessible outside query it comes from. If you want to reuse that data you should save it to tmp table

```
;with tmpFolderPermissions(fp_folder, DataItem, fp_modify) as 
(
    select 
        fp_folder, LEFT(fp_modify, CHARINDEX(',',fp_modify+',')-1),
        STUFF(fp_modify, 1, CHARINDEX(',',fp_modify+','), '')
    from dbo.tblFolderPermissions

    union all

    select 
        fp_folder, CAST (LEFT(fp_modify, CHARINDEX(',', fp_modify+',') -1) AS VARCHAR(200)),
        STUFF(fp_modify, 1, CHARINDEX(',',fp_modify+','), '')
    from tmpFolderPermissions
    where fp_modify > ''
)
select fp_folder, DataItem into #tmpFolderPermissions
from tmpFolderPermissions
```

and then query on #tmpFolderPermissions